# Generic<T> Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I have some manager(singleton) which have some coroutines in it and I want to StopAllCorountines with a simple method. is it possible make a generic type to stop all manager that pass in?

I have not be able to make it work, but is it something like this?

```
void StopAllCorountinesInAllManager<T>(T manager)
{
    manager.instance.StopAllCorountines();
}

StopAllCoruntinesInAllManager(manager1);
StopAllCoruntinesInAllManager(manager2);
StopAllCoruntinesInAllManager(manager3);
```

Comment: Hi there. Try adding something like 'where T: GameObject' after your method in the example. This will only work of course if your managers are GameObjects. If they are not, I will post an answer for a different solution.

Comment: I managed to make it work by making a new class with where T and adding the method in to the generic class. is this what you meant?......................

public abstract class GenericManager<T> where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static void StopAllCoroutinesInManager(T manager)
    {
        manager.StopAllCoroutines();
    }
}

..........Calling by doing this...........
GenericManager<Manager1>.StopAllCoroutinesInManager(Manager1.Instance);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your generic method a type hint:

```
void StopAllCoroutinesInAllManager<T>(T manager) where T : GameObject
{
    manager.StopAllCorountines();
}
```

Call it by passing the instance:

```
StopAllCoroutinesInManager(manager1.Instance);
```

Or alternatively, if your managers are not GameObjects, create an interface, for example:

```
public interface IManager
{
    void StopAllCoroutines();
}
```

And change your generic method as such:

```
void StopAllCoroutinesInAllManager(IManager manager)
{
    manager.StopAllCorountines();
}
```

Then in your manager class implement the interface and have the implementation stop all coroutines. But in this case you could just call StopAllCoroutines on the manager directly.

This should allow you to iterate through a list of managers and stop all coroutines.

Pass the instance of the manager to your function.

Comment: it says 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Instance' and no accessible extension method 'Instance' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found.....is it because of the manager is static type?

Comment: Yes you must pass in the instance. I'll update the code.

Comment: There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Manager1' to 'IManager'....Am I passing it wrong?......I used the interface method and calling it by StopAllCorountinesInAllManager(Manager1.Instance);

Comment: Ah!..I got it now Thanks alot!

Comment: Fantastic. p.s. I made some simplifications to the code afterwards. Good luck